# Enunciate JSON Doc Example Not Displaying Root Element

Tags: enunciate

I am using enunciate 1.26.2.  In the XML/JSON Examples the XML code example is correct but the JSON example is missing the root (SerialPorts)

XML:

```
<SerialPorts> 
    <serialport> 
     <ns1:portId xmlns:ns1="serialPorts">1</ns1:portId> 
     <ns1:portname xmlns:ns1="serialPorts">/dev/tty/foo - Serial</ns1:portname> 
     <ns1:status xmlns:ns1="serialPorts">Port is Active</ns1:status>
    </serialport> 
    <serialport> 
    <!--...-->
    </serialport>
     <!--...more "serialport" elements...--> 
</SerialPorts>
```

JSON:

```
{ "serialport" : [ 
{ "portId" : "1", "portname" : "/dev/tty/foo - Serial", "status" : "Port is Active " }, 
... ] }
```

The output from a real Rest call (using CXF) for both JSON and XML are correct.  I think I'm missing an enunciate JSON annotation/configuration for correct documentation output?

Comment: possibly related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128613/wrapped-example-json-with-enunciate

Comment: So I can't tell exactly what you're expecting. What _should_ the generated docs look like?